# Risks of photographing sensitive information using Android devices?

Tags: android, data-leakage

Sometimes I have to photograph sensitive documents such as bank checks or tax forms etc. Is it completely safe to do with a smartphone, or can there be security threats?

Notably, the legit apps in our phones seem to have a lot of AI activities, changes, and the phones consume approx 100MB to 500MB data per day even when not in use. 
This makes me think of if there could be security risks or surveillance threats.

Is there any additional risk if the phone is Chinese-originated?

Comment: Have you checked with the terms of service ? you might find how they use your assets.

Comment: apropos of the last part of your question, saw this yesterday: https://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2020/04/30/exclusive-warning-over-chinese-mobile-giant-xiaomi-recording-millions-of-peoples-private-web-and-phone-use/#66ecd6241b2a .  Speaking for myself, I make a distinction between "made in china" (often unavoidable) and "company is chinese" (which I refuse to touch).  Even that is a compromise, in my opinion, but practically not much more one can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it completely safe to do with a smartphone

"Completely safe" is a myth.

> or can there be security threats?

The security threats depends upon what application you got installed on the phone and other varying factors too.

> This makes me think of if there could be security risks or surveillance threats.

You need to look into processes and connections, and examine the data in transit to affirm the claim.

> Is there any additional risk if the phone is Chinese-originated?

Most chips are manufactured in China. There are speculations that the Chinese government asked companies to embedded smartphone chips with obfuscated monitoring microchips, but some deny it. Please check your own model and make OR consider buying a trusted device examined earlier.